# Page Viewer Web Part Displays Excel file but not Chart

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, internet-explorer, page-viewer-web-part, chart

I am using SharePoint online. On a Wiki Page, I have added a Page Viewer Web Part in order to embed an Excel file. I am using this web part instead of Excel Web Access because not all of my users have Office 365.

I got the link for the Excel file from the document library "copy link" feature and chose "People with existing Access". Access shouldn't be an issue since I am a global admin anyway.

The page loads with the excel file embedded, except the chart does not load. Instead, I see this graphic where the chart should be:

[image: Graphic that displays when chart does not load]

This is the same graphic that always shows while a chart is loading. Except it normally disappears after less than a second.

Now here's where it gets weird: this was working a few days ago. Not only that, I have another wiki page using the same configuration that is still working even today. Both pages are using the same linked CSS.

Furthermore, both pages work fine on Firefox, but only one works on IE.

Ctrl+F5 makes no difference, clearing the IE browser cache and rebooting makes no difference. I did a full reset of IE back to  default, with no change. other users are affected.

I assumed that the Excel file was to blame, so I took the excel file from the working page and copied it over the non-working one. This also failed. I saw the spreadsheet change to the working spreadsheet, but the chart still didn't load. This means it's not the file.

I'm using IE 11 (11.950.17134.0).
Another computer using IE 11 (11.864.17763.0) has the same issue.
The issue is present in Edge as well.
Works on Chrome for PC and Android.

The document mode in IE seems to be set to IE10. if I open F12 developer tools and manually change it to IE11, the issues goes away. But the solution does not persist once the F12 window is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after spending all afternoon on this, I have found my own answer. Thought I'd post here in case others have the same issue.

It seems that charts are no longer compatible with IE10. However, my master page had this line in the header:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />`

I changed it to:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />`

and it was resolved.